# LXML/Python - Looping over a list of lxml.etree._Element

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, lxml, lxml.html

I'm trying to loop over a list of 5 lxml._Element.

Here is an extract of the part of the html I'm interested in:

```
    <div style="" id="ember140" class="pv-deferred-area ember-view">  <div class="pv-deferred-area__content">
        <!---->

  </div>
</div>
<div id="oc-background-section" class="pv-oc ember-view">              <span class="background-details">
              <div id="ember217" class="ember-view"><section id="ember218" class="pv-profile-section pv-profile-section--reorder-enabled background-section artdeco-container-card ember-view"><div id="ember219" class="pv-profile-section-pager ember-view">    <section id="experience-section" class="pv-profile-section experience-section ember-view"><header class="pv-profile-section__card-header">
  <h2 class="pv-profile-section__card-heading">
    Expérience
  </h2>

<a data-control-name="add_position" href="/in/gregoire-de-kermel/edit/position/new/" id="ember221" class="pv-profile-section__header-add-action add-position artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--circle ember-view">      <li-icon type="plus-icon" role="img" aria-label="Ajouter un nouveau poste"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21 13h-8v8h-2v-8H3v-2h8V3h2v8h8v2z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</a></header>


  <ul class="pv-profile-section__section-info section-info pv-profile-section__section-info--has-more">
<li id="ember223" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view">        <section id="1571672557" class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view">  <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
    <div class="display-flex flex-column full-width">
<a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/company/reputation-squad/" id="ember226" class="full-width ember-view">          <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQE__TgCl2fyUw/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1593648000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=VLSKEVUbJDcULtQwEdrHrH5Gxwq_j7tk2HczgAKn7YU" loading="lazy" alt="Reputation Squad" id="ember228" class="pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image loaded ember-view">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section ">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Data Scientist</h3>
  <p class="visually-hidden">Nom de l’entreprise</p>
  <p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      Reputation Squad
        <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator">Contrat en alternance</span>
  </p>
    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates d’emploi</span>
      <span>janv. 2020 – Aujourd’hui</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Durée d’emploi</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">4 mois</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

  <h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Lieu</span>
    <span>Région de Paris, France</span>
  </h4>

<!---->
</div>

</a>
<!---->    </div>

      <div class="pv-entity__actions">
<a data-control-name="edit_position" href="/in/gregoire-de-kermel/edit/position/1571672557/" id="ember230" class="pv-profile-section__edit-action pv-profile-section__hoverable-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--circle ember-view">          <li-icon type="pencil-icon" role="img" aria-label="Modifier le poste Data Scientist"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21.71 5L19 2.29a1 1 0 00-.71-.29 1 1 0 00-.7.29L4 15.85 2 22l6.15-2L21.71 6.45a1 1 0 00.29-.74 1 1 0 00-.29-.71zM6.87 18.64l-1.5-1.5L15.92 6.57l1.5 1.5zM18.09 7.41l-1.5-1.5 1.67-1.67 1.5 1.5z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</a><!---->      </div>
  </div>
</section>
</li><li id="ember232" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view">        <section id="1516596236" class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view">  <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
    <div class="display-flex flex-column full-width">
<a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/company/credit-agricole-de-la-touraine-et-du-poitou-crto-/" id="ember235" class="full-width ember-view">          <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQHz0qZ2RutURA/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1593648000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=uzqwKV9Un5c_b7X3Xo7vqA2KXcQkmBRDWpMUO5Bu1Gc" loading="lazy" alt="Crédit Agricole de la Touraine et du Poitou" id="ember237" class="pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image loaded ember-view">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section mb2">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Data Scientist</h3>
  <p class="visually-hidden">Nom de l’entreprise</p>
  <p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      Crédit Agricole de la Touraine et du Poitou
        <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator">Contrat en alternance</span>
  </p>
    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates d’emploi</span>
      <span>sept. 2019 – janv. 2020</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Durée d’emploi</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">5 mois</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

  <h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Lieu</span>
    <span>Région de Poitiers, France</span>
  </h4>

<!---->
</div>

</a>
        <div id="ember239" class="pv-entity__extra-details t-14 t-black--light ember-view"><p style="line-height:2rem;max-height:8rem;" id="ember240" class="pv-entity__description t-14 t-black t-normal inline-show-more-text inline-show-more-text--is-collapsed ember-view">• Web scraping (Python)<br>• Etude de profilage client (SAS)<br>• Mise en place d'un projet de système de recommandation (Hadoop, SAS, Python)

<!----></p><!----></div>
    </div>

      <div class="pv-entity__actions">
<a data-control-name="edit_position" href="/in/gregoire-de-kermel/edit/position/1516596236/" id="ember241" class="pv-profile-section__edit-action pv-profile-section__hoverable-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--circle ember-view">          <li-icon type="pencil-icon" role="img" aria-label="Modifier le poste Data Scientist"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21.71 5L19 2.29a1 1 0 00-.71-.29 1 1 0 00-.7.29L4 15.85 2 22l6.15-2L21.71 6.45a1 1 0 00.29-.74 1 1 0 00-.29-.71zM6.87 18.64l-1.5-1.5L15.92 6.57l1.5 1.5zM18.09 7.41l-1.5-1.5 1.67-1.67 1.5 1.5z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</a><!---->      </div>
  </div>
</section>
</li><li id="ember243" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view">        <section id="1427380111" class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view">  <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
    <div class="display-flex flex-column full-width">
<a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/company/weblagence/" id="ember246" class="full-width ember-view">          <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQHOw0tfMPSiWA/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1593648000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=NqZ8eTVFqA2MK4B1ZFUSE7NgTL_ZPqBIMrexzcYnNok" loading="lazy" alt="WebL'Agence" id="ember248" class="pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image loaded ember-view">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section mb2">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Python &amp; React Native developer junior</h3>
  <p class="visually-hidden">Nom de l’entreprise</p>
  <p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      WebL'Agence
<!---->  </p>
    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates d’emploi</span>
      <span>janv. 2019 – août 2019</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Durée d’emploi</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">8 mois</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

  <h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Lieu</span>
    <span>Région de Paris, France</span>
  </h4>

<!---->
</div>

</a>
        <div id="ember250" class="pv-entity__extra-details t-14 t-black--light ember-view"><p style="line-height:2rem;max-height:8rem;" id="ember251" class="pv-entity__description t-14 t-black t-normal inline-show-more-text inline-show-more-text--is-collapsed ember-view">• Création d’applications mobiles (React-Native)<br>• Développement d’un modèle d’évaluation de startup «&nbsp;early-stage&nbsp;»<br>• Web scraping (Selenium Python)<br>• Gestionnaire d’un projet de Machine-Learing/OCR+ (externalisation auprès de prestataires externes et utilisation de AWS textract)

    <span class="inline-show-more-text__link-container-collapsed">
        <span>…</span>
      <button class="inline-show-more-text__button link" aria-expanded="false" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-341="341">
        voir plus
      </button>
    </span>

<!----></p><!----></div>
    </div>

      <div class="pv-entity__actions">
<a data-control-name="edit_position" href="/in/gregoire-de-kermel/edit/position/1427380111/" id="ember252" class="pv-profile-section__edit-action pv-profile-section__hoverable-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--circle ember-view">          <li-icon type="pencil-icon" role="img" aria-label="Modifier le poste Python &amp;amp; React Native developer junior"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21.71 5L19 2.29a1 1 0 00-.71-.29 1 1 0 00-.7.29L4 15.85 2 22l6.15-2L21.71 6.45a1 1 0 00.29-.74 1 1 0 00-.29-.71zM6.87 18.64l-1.5-1.5L15.92 6.57l1.5 1.5zM18.09 7.41l-1.5-1.5 1.67-1.67 1.5 1.5z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</a><!---->      </div>
  </div>
</section>
</li><li id="ember254" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view">        <section id="708026390" class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view">  <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
    <div class="display-flex flex-column full-width">
<a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/search/results/all/?keywords=Gauthier%20Associ%C3%A9s" id="ember257" class="full-width ember-view">          <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" loading="lazy" alt="Gauthier Associés" id="ember259" class="pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image ghost-company loaded ember-view">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section mb2">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Business Financial Analyst</h3>
  <p class="visually-hidden">Nom de l’entreprise</p>
  <p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      Gauthier Associés
<!---->  </p>
    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates d’emploi</span>
      <span>juil. 2015 – juin 2019</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Durée d’emploi</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">4 ans</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

  <h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Lieu</span>
    <span>Smarves</span>
  </h4>

<!---->
</div>

</a>
        <div id="ember261" class="pv-entity__extra-details t-14 t-black--light ember-view"><p style="line-height:2rem;max-height:8rem;" id="ember262" class="pv-entity__description t-14 t-black t-normal inline-show-more-text inline-show-more-text--is-collapsed ember-view">It started as a 2 months internship in which my tasks were to:<br>• Analysed the company's profitability<br>•   Created the official corporate document on profitability<br>•   Designed and administered a corporate customer satisfaction survey<br><br>Ever since, I am doing yearly financial and business analysis under my own business. It has been now 4 years that I am working with this company, with more and more responsibilities over the time such reporting and analysing the company's investing holdings' profitability.

    <span class="inline-show-more-text__link-container-collapsed">
        <span>…</span>
      <button class="inline-show-more-text__button link" aria-expanded="false" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-342="342">
        voir plus
      </button>
    </span>

<!----></p><!----></div>
    </div>

      <div class="pv-entity__actions">
<a data-control-name="edit_position" href="/in/gregoire-de-kermel/edit/position/708026390/" id="ember263" class="pv-profile-section__edit-action pv-profile-section__hoverable-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--circle ember-view">          <li-icon type="pencil-icon" role="img" aria-label="Modifier le poste Business Financial Analyst"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21.71 5L19 2.29a1 1 0 00-.71-.29 1 1 0 00-.7.29L4 15.85 2 22l6.15-2L21.71 6.45a1 1 0 00.29-.74 1 1 0 00-.29-.71zM6.87 18.64l-1.5-1.5L15.92 6.57l1.5 1.5zM18.09 7.41l-1.5-1.5 1.67-1.67 1.5 1.5z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</a><!---->      </div>
  </div>
</section>
</li><li id="ember265" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view">        <section id="813743952" class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view">  <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
    <div class="display-flex flex-column full-width">
<a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/company/gsma/" id="ember268" class="full-width ember-view">          <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQGmHE5IziHPfw/company-logo_100_100/0?e=1593648000&amp;v=beta&amp;t=uonj7aae0F9Qr9Z7uDJAjX358njW5zCqaCrhF-m5wJU" loading="lazy" alt="GSMA" id="ember270" class="pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image loaded ember-view">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section mb2">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Intern Analyst - Network 2020</h3>
  <p class="visually-hidden">Nom de l’entreprise</p>
  <p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      GSMA
<!---->  </p>
    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates d’emploi</span>
      <span>mai 2016 – juil. 2016</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Durée d’emploi</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">3 mois</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

  <h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Lieu</span>
    <span>London, Royaume-Uni</span>
  </h4>

<!---->
</div>

</a>
        <div id="ember272" class="pv-entity__extra-details t-14 t-black--light ember-view"><p style="line-height:2rem;max-height:8rem;" id="ember273" class="pv-entity__description t-14 t-black t-normal inline-show-more-text inline-show-more-text--is-collapsed ember-view">Initially, I had the opportunity to use small and large data sets to reconcile, analyse and present to key stakeholders – developing strong excel capability in the process.<br><br>Further developing these skills, I had the opportunity to deliver a project of work (end-to-end) from developing communications for data requests, clean data collection and storage processes and then developing a methodology for estimating market size metrics in a sustainable reporting process to the Network 2020 programme.<br><br>Summary of milestones:<br>•    Reconciling, analysing and presenting information to key stakeholders<br>•  Request, store and model market estimations<br>•    Researching, collection and storing and communicating key business metrics

    <span class="inline-show-more-text__link-container-collapsed">
        <span>…</span>
      <button class="inline-show-more-text__button link" aria-expanded="false" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-343="343">
        voir plus
      </button>
    </span>

<!----></p><!----></div>
    </div>

      <div class="pv-entity__actions">
<a data-control-name="edit_position" href="/in/gregoire-de-kermel/edit/position/813743952/" id="ember274" class="pv-profile-section__edit-action pv-profile-section__hoverable-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--circle ember-view">          <li-icon type="pencil-icon" role="img" aria-label="Modifier le poste Intern Analyst - Network 2020"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
  <path d="M21.71 5L19 2.29a1 1 0 00-.71-.29 1 1 0 00-.7.29L4 15.85 2 22l6.15-2L21.71 6.45a1 1 0 00.29-.74 1 1 0 00-.29-.71zM6.87 18.64l-1.5-1.5L15.92 6.57l1.5 1.5zM18.09 7.41l-1.5-1.5 1.67-1.67 1.5 1.5z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</a><!---->      </div>
  </div>
</section>
</li>  </ul>

  <div id="ember275" class="pv-experience-section__see-more pv-profile-section__actions-inline ember-view"><button class="pv-profile-section__see-more-inline pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle link link-without-hover-state" aria-expanded="false">Afficher 1 expérience de plus
<li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-down-icon" class="pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M8 9l5.93-4L15 6.54l-6.15 4.2a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.69 0L1 6.54 2.07 5z"></path>
</svg></li-icon></button>

<!----></div>
```

I've save the extract under an html file and opened it the following way:

```
def parse_html_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, encoding="utf8").read()
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO(f), parser)
    return tree

tree = parse_html_file('test.html')
```

I have 5 elements in my list `"pv-profile-section__section-info section-info pv-profile-section__section-info--has-more"`.

The goal is to extract the job name, company name and contract type.

So far, I've done the following:

```
job_location = tree.xpath(
    './/li[@class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view"]')

di = {}

for i in job_location:
    try:
        di['name'] = tree.xpath(
            '//h3[@class="t-16 t-black t-bold"]/text()')
    except:
        di['name'] = 'None'
    try:
        di['name'] = tree.xpath(
            '//h3[@class="t-16 t-black t-bold"]/text()')
    except:
        di['name'] = 'None'    
    try:
        di['contract'] = tree.xpath(
            '//span[@class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator"]/text()')
    except:
        di['contract'] = 'None'

print(di)
```

It seems to be working but right now, the lenght of the "job" and "company" variables are both 5 while "contract_type" is 2.
I would like to print something is there is no "contract_type" attribute inside the original loop like for the last element. When there is nothing, I'd like to display "None" for the contract_type.

What I have so far:

```
{'name': ['Data Scientist', 'Data Scientist', 'Python & React Native developer junior', 'Business Financial Analyst', 'Intern Analyst - Network 2020'], 'contract': ['Contrat en alternance', 'Contrat en alternance']}
```

What I'd like to get:

{'name': ['Data Scientist', 'Data Scientist', 'Python & React Native developer junior', 'Business Financial Analyst', 'Intern Analyst - Network 2020'], 'contract': ['Contrat en alternance', 'Contrat en alternance', '', '', '']}

Do you guys could give me a hint on this task?

Comment: Your xml is invalid; can you please edit and fix it?

Comment: @JackFleeting Thanks for replying. I've change the post. The source code can be found here: https://www.linkedin.com/in/gregoire-de-kermel/ (it's my linkedin page)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question**. We should not have to log in to LinkedIn to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Why is the question tagged with both "python-3.x" and "python-2.7"?

Comment: Your xml is still invalid; try running it through one of the online xml validators.

Comment: @JackFleeting Thanks. I've modify it again, on 2 different tools. One says it's ok, the other don't... But I've try to open it the way I'm explaining in my question, it works for sure

Comment: @JackFleeting But this is about HTML, which isn't necessarily well-formed. `etree.HTMLParser()` is used in the question.

Comment: @mzjn - True, but I suspect that the original is actually well formed (it's Linkedin, after all) which, if true, will make it easier to test various xpath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, something like this is what you may be looking for.

It basically creates two lists: a long one (for "name") and a short one (for "contract"), then pads the shortest list to the length of the longest list with "NA" (or whatever) and, finally, adds the two equal-length lists to the dictionary.

Note that `job_location` now starts at the **parent** of the node in your question (which probably caused some of the confusion).

```
job_location = tree.xpath('.//ul[@class="pv-profile-section__section-info section-info pv-profile-section__section-info--has-more"]')
for jl in job_location:
    desc = jl.xpath('//h3[@class="t-16 t-black t-bold"]/text()')
    cont = jl.xpath('//span[@class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator"]/text()')
    name = []
    contract = []
    di = {}

    for d in desc:
        name.append(d)
    for c in cont:
        contract.append(c)
    contract += ['NA'] * (len(name) - len(contract)) #this is where the padding takes place
    di['name'] = name
    di['contract'] = contract
print(di)
```

Output:

```
{'name': ['Data Scientist', 'Data Scientist', 'Python & React Native developer junior', 'Business Financial Analyst', 'Intern Analyst - Network 2020'], 'contract': ['Contrat en alternance', 'Contrat en alternance', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It works for this particular case but it won't be replicatable. The filling with 'NA' needs to be "dynamic" and check every index before filling with 'NA' or the given value

Comment: @GrégoiredeKermel I'm not sure what you mean by that, but generally speaking I (and everyone else) can only work with information provided in your question - we know nothing about anything outside of that.